# Display Colorframe in kinect in Full screen

Tags: windows, kinect

I want to display the kinect color frame in wpf with full screen , but when i am trying it ,
I got only very less quality video frames.

How to do  this any idea??

Comment: This is very basic and can be easily found by googling -1

Answer (score 4):

The Kinect camera doesn't have great resolutions. Only 640x480 and 1280x960 are supported. Forcing these images to take up the entire screen, especially if you're using a high definition monitor (1920x1080, for example), will cause the image to be stretched, which generally looks awful. It's the same problem you run into if you try to make any image larger; each pixel in the original image has to fill up more pixels in the expanded image, causing the image to look blocky.

Really, the only thing to minimize this is to make sure you're using the Kinect's maximum color stream resolution. You can do that by specifying a ColorImageFormat when you enable the ColorStream. Note that this resolution has a significantly lower number of frames per second than the 640x480 stream (12 FPS vs 30 FPS). However, it should look better in a fullscreen mode than the alternative.

```
sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution1280x960Fps12);
```